# Change the background color of a WPF editable ComboBox programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm trying to dynamically change the background color of an editable `ComboBox` at runtime, using code. In particular, I want to change the background of the editable `TextBox` that is part of the `ComboBox`.

There are several answers about this on SO, like this one:

[WPF change the background color of an edittable combobox in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147838/wpf-change-the-background-color-of-an-edittable-combobox-in-code)

however, the problem is that they're all based on `XAML` and editing default templates. I don't want to do that, I'm searching for a generic solution that works with just code.

Is it possible? I tried the solution that seems obvious:

```
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)comboBox.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", comboBox);
textBox.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
```

But this does absolutely nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you want to change a single ComboBox, or all editable ComboBoxes?

Comment: try it: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/84637/TIP-Change-background-of-WPF-Combobox

Comment: @Wimmel: a single one

Comment: @ChristophKn: if you read my question properly, you'll understand why that isn't the case. That answer, as I pointed out, is based on editing the ComboBox default XAML template (which btw, VS 2015 won't even let me do). I'm searching for a way to edit the background of a single combobox directly in code

Comment: @Roma: that changes the color of the drop-down menu, not of the editable TextBox where the user can enter text.

Comment: set `ComboBox.Background` should change the background of the editable textbox only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do it

```
<ComboBox Loaded="MyCombo_OnLoaded"  x:Name="myCombo" IsEditable="True"></ComboBox>

private void MyCombo_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      var textbox = (TextBox)myCombo.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", myCombo);
      if (textbox!= null)
      {
           var parent = (Border)textbox.Parent;
           parent.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
       }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, and super simple too.

Comment: good stuff indeed! i cant use normal validation and implemented a custom validation using this and a color property on my viewmodel

Comment: Wow, really, that's what it takes to change the background color?  That alone is a good reason to never consider WPF over WinForms.  **Question:** How do we find the information necessary to figure out stuff like "PART_EditableTextBox" on our own instead of asking you for each detail that we want to change?  I need to be able to find the information using reference material, not reading through XAML or using any tool involving XAML.  I don't use visual studio or blend and I don't use XAML.

Answer (score 2):

Reusable AttachedProperty solution for xaml only fans:

```
<ComboBox Background="Orange" IsEditable="True" Text="hi" local:ComboBoxHelper.EditBackground="Red"></ComboBox>
```

Implementation:

```
public static class ComboBoxHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EditBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "EditBackground", typeof (Brush), typeof (ComboBoxHelper), new PropertyMetadata(default(Brush), EditBackgroundChanged));

    private static void EditBackgroundChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var combo = dependencyObject as ComboBox;
        if (combo != null)
        {
            if (!combo.IsLoaded)
            {
                RoutedEventHandler comboOnLoaded = null;
                comboOnLoaded = delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs eventArgs)
                {
                    EditBackgroundChanged(dependencyObject, args);
                    combo.Loaded -= comboOnLoaded;
                };
                combo.Loaded += comboOnLoaded;

                return;
            }

            var part = combo.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", combo);
            var tb = part as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                var parent = tb.Parent as Border;
                if (parent != null)
                {
                    parent.Background = (Brush)args.NewValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(ComboBox))]
    public static void SetEditBackground(DependencyObject element, Brush value)
    {
        element.SetValue(EditBackgroundProperty, value);
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(ComboBox))]
    public static Brush GetEditBackground(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (Brush) element.GetValue(EditBackgroundProperty);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Master_T Thanks. This implementation also has the advantage that it can be applied to the default style, without fiddling around on every combobox. AttachedProperties are some of the really useful features of WPF