# How to change the background color of an editable combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

[image: screenshot]

I want to change my combobox background color. When the combobox is not editable, it worked successfully. But when I change my combobox's `IsEditable = True`, the background color is fixed to only white.

I tried this method ([Change the background color of a WPF editable ComboBox programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177619/change-the-background-color-of-a-wpf-editable-combobox-programmatically)). But it doesn't work for my window.

This is my XAML markup:

```
<ComboBox FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Name="combo" IsEditable="True" TabIndex="0" Margin="146,114,164,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Padding="6,5,5,3" BorderBrush="Black" Background="#FFDDDDDD">
```

Comment: Why the linked solution didn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

There's a solved question in StackOverflow. I compiled and tested that code. It works.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177619/change-the-background-color-of-a-wpf-editable-combobox-programmatically)

You can use the code in this link or you can write a style.

```
<Style x:Key="MyCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}"></Style>
```

Create a resource dictionary or add style as resource to checkbox directly. You can make that by using template too.

Comment: This is not true. You _can_ change the background color in XAML. For that, you need to change the control's template. This can be done in pure XAML.

Comment: I forgot the template setter.