# WPF MVVM ComboBox color

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I want to change background color of my ComboBox. I mean background color of the comboBox, not items in popup list, see the picture. That's all I need! Why this is so difficult to do!? Why this doesn't work out of the box? I would like to find solution in MVVM-approach, without hacks in code-behind, etc.

[image]

p.s. Of course I've tried all suggestions from similar discussions - it doesn't work for me (Windows 10 - maybe this is important).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the default style you'll understand why it *doesn't work out of the box*. See below where `CustomBrush1` is applied to change the color you want:

```
    <Window.Resources>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomBrush1" Color="#2fff0000"/>

    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFACACAC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border" Color="#FFABADB3"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF000000"/>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFEBF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF000000"/>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFDAECFC" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFDAEBFC" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFD9D9D9"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF606060"/>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{StaticResource CustomBrush1}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="F1 M 0,0 L 2.667,2.66665 L 5.3334,0 L 5.3334,-1.78168 L 2.6667,0.88501 L0,-1.78168 L0,0 Z" Fill="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Glyph}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Border}"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Border}"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                    <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                            <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
            </Popup>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="dropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="Transparent" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                    <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                            <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
            </Popup>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>
            <Border x:Name="border" Background="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Background}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTextBox}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="dropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,5,3"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" 
              Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle1}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
              Margin="0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
              Width="120" 
              />

</Grid>
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Note though you may not be able to make it much smaller just because you're changing things inside the `ControlTemplate`. And whilst you can have a `Style` that is `BasedOn` another style, which reduces the amount of necessary XAML, the same is NOT true with a `Template`. With a `Template` you have to copy **everything**.

Here's a quote from **Adam Nathan**'s excellent book, *WPF Unleashed*:

> There is no mechanism for tweaking existing templates (like Style’s BasedOn). Instead, you can easily retrieve a XAML representation for any existing (...) template, modify it, and then apply it as a brand-new (...) template.

Comment: Upvote for referring to the default style. So many WPF questions can be answered (and lots of tricks learned) by looking at those styles and learning from them.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you Sir.

Comment: OK, thanks, looks frighteningly large. Is it possible to get result with less of xaml-code? That what I still can't accept: I need to change JUST ONE property: background color. If this required so many code (much more than all my project contains!!!) - what can I say, WPF is monster.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is possible. Visual Studio pulls everything necessary, so i posted it so you can understand what is going on. But once you understand the default style and templates you could reduce it to the minimum necessary to make the changes you want.

Comment: Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: It is true, ComboBox style in Windows 8 and later - works different: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32148484/6327162 

This is very strange, why we have to copy huge std style, but that's all I found, no short solution.